# why can't I perform a dynamic cast? Strategy pattern in C

Tags: c++, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to implement the strategy pattern in C++ to make my code more flexible (and get to learn some OO programing). The dynamic cast showing up on the 3rd line in main() fails. Also I get some quite wierd error messages. Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I'm not used to using design patterns in C++.

The error message I get from the compiler:

```
/*
/tmp/cc8b482g.o: In function `individual::setObjectiveFunction(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to `ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl::ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl()'
/tmp/cc8b482g.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl::ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl::~ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl::~ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl()'
*/
```

Edit: There was a correct suggestion from "6502" that I was using a class before it was declared (this is a trimmed version of the whole code)

The constructor of ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl are there, arent they?

What am I missing, the declaration is now right above from where it is used and it still doesn't work...

Thanx in advance again!

And many thanx for the fast responses! - This is my first question in Stack Overflow,
I promise I'll repay the deed helping other programers when I become a better programer!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
class individual;
class objectiveFunctionStrategy;

/*
 * This is my abstract class implementation for a strategy.
 */
class objectiveFunctionStrategy
{
public:
    objectiveFunctionStrategy();
    virtual ~objectiveFunctionStrategy();
    virtual float evaluate(individual)=0;
};

/*
 * The class individual should contain strategy objects
 */
class individual{
    private:
        std::vector<float>                 featureVector;
        objectiveFunctionStrategy *        ofstrategy;
        unsigned int ndim;

    public:
        /*Constructors*/
        individual(std::vector<float>);
        float getObjectiveFunction();
        void setObjectiveFunction(int k);
        std::vector<float> getFeatureVector();
};

individual::individual(std::vector<float> fv){
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<fv.size() ; i++){
        featureVector.push_back(fv[i]);
    }
    this -> ndim = featureVector.size();
}

std::vector<float> individual::getFeatureVector(){
    return this->featureVector;
}

float individual::getObjectiveFunction(){
    /*
     *Here I'm planning of passing a concrete strategy object to 
     *make the objective functions interchangeable.
     * 
     *So the calculation would be ofstrategy.evaluate()
     */
    float Fc=0;
    if(false == false){
        std::vector<float> vv = this->featureVector;
        Fc = ofstrategy->evaluate(vv);
    }
    return Fc;
}

/*
 * Now this one is a concrete strategy object class:
 */
class ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl: public objectiveFunctionStrategy
{
public:
    /*
     * could have a reference to the individual.
     * might do things a bit more complicated.
     */
    ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl();    
    ~ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl();

    float evaluate(individual ind){
        float Fc =0 ;
        std::vector<float> v = ind.getFeatureVector();
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
            Fc += v[i]*v[i];
        }
        return Fc;
    }
};

void individual::setObjectiveFunction(int i){
    /*
     * here the strategy is defined inside the class by an integer
     */
    this->ofstrategy = new ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl;
}


int main(){
    std::vector<float> v;
    ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl hb;
    objectiveFunctionStrategy* ofs;
    ofs = dynamic_cast<objectiveFunctionStrategy*> (&hb);
    individual indiv(v);
    /*
     * Now the above still does not compile...
     * error message:
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    v.push_back(2.1);
    v.push_back(22.1);
    hb.evaluate(indiv);
}
```

Comment: There will be more errors after you fix your original question.
`hb.evaluate(indiv);` uses `indiv` variable, which is not defined. Plus, you pass it by value to `hb.evaluate`. Const reference will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanx! This is a heavilly trimmed version of my code that reproduces the problem. I thought of that, my first approach was to keep a reference to the "individual" inside the strategy object and then just call bd.evaluate(). I'm not that confident right now though to write that in C++...

Answer (score 4):

Your code is using

```
new ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl;
```

before declaring the class `ObjectiveFunctionhyperBowl`; C++ doesn't do a look-ahead in this case so you must declare the class before using it.

Moving the class declaration before the `individual::setObjectiveFunction` method implementation should suffice. In general it's however better to have if possible all declarations (and only declarations) in an include `.h` file, and the implementation in a `.cpp` separate file.

Comment: I have corrected that and it still doesn't work. Actually the error message I get now is my original one. This is a trimmed version of the code used to reproduce the message. Thanx for the fast reply and for the interest!

Comment: @user1941126: The error is now a linking error. You declared constructor and destructor but there is no implementation for them.

Comment: After implementing 6502's suggestion, just add brackets {} to implement the constructors and destructors and it will compile.
http://pastebin.com/iuKjxg8J